# Looking for formula to search duplicates in adjacent columns and get address

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to calculate monthly volatility for 5 years and so far it has proven  to be quite a complex task.  What I have is two adjacent columns one is with month number and the next is with the year.  I tried doing INDEX MATCH but realized that it returns the first cell it finds.  For instance if it is going to look up June it searches for 6 but it returns the first 6 it finds (in my case in year 2018).  So what I am trying to do is for the formula to return the address of the cell that matches the month in column 1 and year in column 2 (for instance 6 and 2017).  I've tried INDEX MATCH  MATCH and it doesn't work.  I was thinking through  trying INDEX 0 MATCH  so it will return  all the rows  but so far it hasn't worked.  I may be doing it wrong.  Can someone provide insight into this

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492758/vlookup-using-2-columns-to-reference-another

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that I cannot comment.

> So what I am trying to do is for the formula to return the address of the cell that matches the month in column 1 and year in column 2

There is a hacky way to use INDEX+MATCH for these kinds of "Matching multiple conditions" problems. Assuming the conditions are in column A and column B, you may use:

`=A1 & " " & B1`

to concatenate the two values and then you can use `INDEX+MATCH` as you are matching one condition, not two.

I'm not sure what the data looks like, so please upload some sample data and I'll see if this works or not.